# Prove $\nabla h(x) = A^T \nabla g(Ax+b)$, $A$ is a square matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I have trouble understanding why this the claim is true:

Let $h(x) = g(Ax+b)$, $A$ some square matrix, then $\nabla h(x) = A^T \nabla g(Ax+b)$

Attempt:

---

Let $F(x) = Ax+b$, then $$\nabla h(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose $a_k$ is the $k$th row in $A$

Then  $$\dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x_k} =  \dfrac{\partial g(F(x))}{\partial F(x)}\dfrac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x_k} =\dfrac{\partial g(F(x))}{\partial F(x)} a_k^T$$

Then collecting all components
 $$\nabla h(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix} = A^T\dfrac{\partial g(F(x))}{\partial F(x)}$$

But $\dfrac{\partial g(F(x))}{\partial F(x)}$ is or is not the gradient of $g(F(x))$? How can I see that?

Comment: The point is that if $A$ is a matrix, then $y=Ax+b$ is a vector. So you actually need $\partial g / \partial y_k$. Writing everything in components actually helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the more general situation in which {$x,b$} are matrices and $A$ is rectangular. For convenience, define the variable $w = (Ax+b).\,\,$  Then we have $h(x)=g(w)$.

I find it helpful to express the differentials in terms of the [Frobenius Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) 
$$\eqalign{
 dh &= \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}:dx \cr
}$$
and
$$\eqalign{
 dg &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial w}:dw \cr
   &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial w}:A\,dx \cr
   &= A^T\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}:dx \cr
}$$
Since we must have $dh=dg$ for arbitrary $dx$, it follows that  $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=A^T\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}$$

**NB:**  Rules for rearranging a Frobenius product follow from its equivalence to the trace, e.g. ${\rm tr}(A^TBC)=A:BC$, and the cyclic property of the trace. For example $$A:BC = B^TA:C$$